# GDB source path

Tags: debugging, path, gdb

How to make gdb to use different directory to look for source files.

For example my source file during the compilation was in directory:

```
/home/foo/bar.c
```

Next, I moved it into directory:

```
/tmp/debug/home/foo/bar.c
```

How to enforce gdb to search in this directory? 
According to [this site](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html) I should just use command:

```
dir /tmp/debug/
```

But it is not working. I get a message `foo.c: "No such file or directory"` from gdb.

Comment: Try using the whole path like `dir /tmp/debug/home/foo`, I think it wants to find just the file itself there.

Comment: I know this works but that's not the case. I just want to automatize some process. If I there will be a lot such files, adding the whole path for each file is like putting all the files in one debug directory. In other words, if you have files with the same names but different directories (during the compilation time) adding the whole paths will cause name conflicts (gdb will not distinguish between this files).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
set substitute-path /home/foo /tmp/debug/home/foo
```

http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html#index-set-substitute_002dpath

Comment: I know this one as well. But just imagine that you have some other files somewhere in your home directory. If you set this substitute-path it will be changed for all files under 'home'.

Comment: Then write a few `set substitute-path`. First `set substitute-path` for those files and folders in your home directory and then `set substitute-path` for those files and folders  for those that are moved. The doc says: `In the case when more than one substitution rule have been defined, the rules are evaluated one by one in the order where they have been defined. The first one matching, if any, is selected to perform the substitution.`