# How to set a breakpoint outside working directory in gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I have run a program in gdb in the directory
first->next1->next2->next3

Now I want to put a break point in a file in directory
first->next1->next2->next4

what I did is

break ../next4/file.c:486 (considering that I am in directory next3)
but it produces error "No such file"

I also tried this

break first/next1/next2/next4/file.c:486
but same result

Comment: I am sure that could be a good start. gdb source path - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868252/gdb-source-path

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried this
>   `break first/next1/next2/next4/file.c:486` but same result

You can find out what paths GDB knows about with `info sources` (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965636/50617)).

Depending on how `first/next1/next2/next4/file.c` was compiled, any one of these may work:

```
break file.c:486
break next4/file.c:486
break next2/next4/file.c:486
break next1/next2/next4/file.c:486
break /full/path/to/first/next1/next2/next4/file.c:486
```